# Mongodb not casting data correctly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

When I post data on database, some data are not stored in my database .

Here's the schema of my model :

```
var ProjSchema = new Schema({
  leadProj: String,
  nomProj: String,
  descProj: String,
  BesProj: Number,
  pers: [
    {
      name: String,
      poste: String
    }
  ],
  backlog: { fonctionnalite: [String], userStory: [String] }
});
```

I use Express for Api and this is the route

```
  .post(function(req, res) {
    var nouvProj = new NouvProj();
    nouvProj.nomProj = req.body.nomProj;
    nouvProj.leadProj = req.body.leadProj;
    nouvProj.descProj = req.body.descProj;
    nouvProj.BesProj = req.body.BesProj;
    nouvProj.pers = req.body.pers;
    nouvProj.backlog.fonctionnalite = req.body.Fonctionnalite;
    nouvProj.backlog.userStory = req.body.UserStory;
    console.log(req.body.Fonctionnalite);
    console.log(req.body.UserStory);

    // save the nouvProj and check for errors
    nouvProj.save(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err);
        console.log("err");
      }
      res.json({
        message: "nouvProj created!"
      });
    });
  })
```

the output of `console.log()`

```
[ { fonctionnalite: 'oijoij' }, { fonctionnalite: 'oio' } ]
[ { userStory: 'oijoij' }, { userStory: 'poihpohi' } ]
```

The problem is on `backlog` item . I'm getting empty data in it when I get elements:

```
backlog : []
```

**Update** : I would precise the difference between `pers` and `backlog`
`Pers` item is a table of {name: String, poste }
`backlog` is table of table of {fonctionnalite: String} and {UserStory : String}

I don't understand why is that working for `pers` and not for `backlog`

Comment: can you check `console.log(nouvProj.backlog.fonctionnalite)` and `console.log(nouvProj.backlog.userStory)`

Comment: `Fonctionnalite` should be an array of strings, but you are supplying an array of objects. Same with `userStory`.

Comment: @MikaS I don't think so as it is a custom object, Idk whether he wants to  to define this "backlog" as an array though or he needs it as an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `req.body.Fonctionnalite` and `req.body.UserStory` are both array of objects and in your shcema they are declared as array of strings, You need to redefine the `ProjSchema` to take over this behavior:

```
var ProjSchema = new Schema({
    leadProj: String,
    nomProj: String,
    descProj: String,
    BesProj: Number,
    pers: [
    {
        name: String,
        poste: String
    }
    ],
    backlog: { 
        fonctionnalite: [ { fonctionnalite: String } ], 
        userStory: [ { userStory: String } ], 
    }
});
```

**Or** you can keep `ProjSchema` as it is and update the front-end code in the way that `fonctionnalite` and `userStory` posted as a normal arrays:

```
fonctionnalite => [ 'oijoij', 'oio' ]
userStory => [ 'oijoij','poihpohi' ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you pass only a string to your `functionalite` while you defined it as an `array`, you should push the value into your array instead of assigning a string to it.

```
nouvProj.backlog.fonctionnalite.push(req.body.Fonctionnalite);
nouvProj.backlog.userStory.push(req.body.UserStory);
```

If you want to define a flexible or loose object (schema-less), its properties or schema  fields are specified at runtime, you can use `Schema.Types.Mixed`

```
//schema defintion
var proj = new Proj({
  myObject: Schema.Types.Mixed
});

//how use it 
var proj = new Proj();
proj.myObject = { any: { fields: ['test'] } }
yourSchema.save()
```

If you want to define your `backlog` as an array, I would suggest doing this.

```
var BackLog = new Schema({ 
 fonctionnalite: [String], 
 userStory: [String] 
};

var ProjSchema = new Schema({
  leadProj: String,
  nomProj: String,
  descProj: String,
  BesProj: Number,
  pers: [
    {
      name: String,
      poste: String
    }
  ],
  backlog: [BackLog]
});

// create a project 
var proj = new ProjSchema({
  ....
});
//you notice functionalite is an array, userStory is also an array 
proj.backlog.push({ functionalite: ['test'], userStory: ['sss'] });

proj.save(function (err) {
  ...
}
```

More info for Mongoose schema and modeling, can be found [here](http://www.jonahnisenson.com/schema-within-a-schema-use-embedded-documents-in-mongoosemongo/) or [Heroku's Dev. blog](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-mongoose).